# Collapse of Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Consider a fibration $F \rightarrow E \rightarrow B$ of "nice spaces" (e.g. compact connected smooth manifolds) with $B$ simply connected so we can ease spectral sequences computations. Suppose also that $H^*(E;\mathbb{Q})$ 
is a free $H^*(B;\mathbb{Q})$-module with the canonical structure induced by the map $E \rightarrow B$. (I will omit writing coefficients from now)

Using the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence, there is a spectral sequence

$$E_2 = Tor_{H^*(B)}(\mathbb{Q}, H^*(E)) \Rightarrow H^*(X) $$

By the condition on $H^*(E)$, the higher Tor terms vanish, then we have that the spectral sequence collapses at this page and $H^*(F) \cong \mathbb{Q} \otimes_{H^*(B)} H^*(E) $.

I want to show that $H^*(E) \cong H^*(B) \otimes H^*(F)$ as $H^*(B)$-modules. So we can use the Leray-Hirsch theorem for instance, but it would need that the map $i^*:H^*(E) \rightarrow H^*(F)$ induced by the inclusion of the fiber $i:F \rightarrow E$ admits an additive section.

> **my question is:**
>   Can we conclude from the isomorphism
>
> $$H^*(F) \cong \mathbb{Q} \otimes_{H^*(B)} H^*(E) $$
>   that $i^*$ is surjective?

Comment: You can probably use naturality of the spectral sequence to deduce that the map $H^*(E)\otimes_{H^*(B)} \mathbb Q \to H^*(F)$ is induced by $H^*(E)\to H^*(F)$, which would prove surjectivity of the latter

Comment: The statement is that the map $i^*:\mathbb{Q}\otimes H^*E\rightarrow H^*F$ factors over the quotient $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{H^*B} H^*E$ to give the isomorphism. Since the quotient map is surjective you should get your question.